# How do I pull the index(es) and column(s) of a specific value from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

---Hello, everyone! New student of Python's Pandas here.

I have a dataframe I artificially constructed here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWgiB.png. Below is a text reconstruction.

```py
df_dict = {
    'header0' : [55,12,13,14,15],
    'header1' : [21,22,23,24,25],
    'header2' : [31,32,55,34,35],
    'header3' : [41,42,43,44,45],
    'header4' : [51,52,53,54,33]
}
index_list = {
    0:'index0',
    1:'index1',
    2:'index2',
    3:'index3',
    4:'index4'
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict).rename(index = index_list)
```

**GOAL:**

I want to pull the index row(s) and column header(s) of any ARBITRARY value(s) (int, float, str, etc.). So for eg, if I want the values of `55`, this code will return: `header0`, `index0`, `header2`, `index2` in some format. They could be list or tuple or print, etc.

**CLARIFICATIONS:**

- Imagine the dataframe is of a large enough size that I cannot "just find it manually"
- I do not know how large this value is in comparison to other values (so a "simple `.idxmax()`" probably won't cut it)
- I do not know where this value is column or index wise (so "just `.loc`,`.iloc` where the value is" won't help either)
- I do not know whether this value has duplicates or not, but if it does, return all its column/indexes.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR:**

I've played around with `.columns`, `.index`, `.loc`, but just can't seem to get the answer. The farthest I've gotten is creating a boolean dataframe with `df.values == 55` or `df == 55`, but cannot seem to do anything with it.

Another "farthest" way I've gotten is using `df.unstack.idxmax()`, which would return a tuple of the column and header, but has 2 major problems:

1. Only returns the max/min as per the `.idxmax()`, `.idxmin()` functions
2. Only returns the FIRST column/index matching my value, which doesn't help if there are duplicates

I know I could do a `for loop` to iterate through the entire dataframe, tracking which column and index I am on in temporary variables. Once I hit the value I am looking for, I'll `break` and return the current column and index. Was just hoping there was a less brute-force-y method out there, since I'd like a "high-speed calculation" method that would work on any dataframe of any size.

Thanks.

EDIT: Added text database, clarified questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
r, c = np.where(df == 55)    
list(zip(df.index[r], df.columns[c]))
```

Output:

```
[('index0', 'header0'), ('index2', 'header2')]
```

Comment: oh my gosh, this is so clean and exactly what I'm looking for! the only question left is how do I give you medals haha (new to stack overflow)

Comment: @ChristopherDenq No need for all that. you upvoted and accepted.  Thank you.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for `Series with MultiIndex` and then filter duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
s = df.unstack()
out = s[s.duplicated(keep=False)].index.tolist()
```

If need also duplicates with values:

```
df1 = (s[s.duplicated(keep=False)]
        .sort_values()
        .rename_axis(index='idx', columns='cols')
        .reset_index(name='val'))
```

If need tet specific value change mask for [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`):

```
s = df.unstack()
out = s[s.eq(55)].index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in pandas that gives duplicate rows.

```
duplicate = df[df.duplicated()]
print(duplicate)
```

Comment: I am aware of that function! Unforunately, that is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for any arbitrary value, and IF that arbitrary value exists, then return all matching column/index headers.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the code below, there is an iteration. However, it doesn't iterate over the whole DataFrame, but it just iterates over the columns, and then use `.any()` to check if there is any of the desierd value. Then using `loc` feature in the pandas it locates the value, and finally returns the `index`.

```
wanted_value = 55

for col in list(df.columns):

    if df[col].eq(wanted_value).any() == True:
        print("row:", *list(df.loc[df[col].eq(wanted_value)].index), ' col', col)
```